# Mailgun sending AND receiving using wildcard subdomains

Tags: mailgun

I want to be able to send from foo@*.mydomain.com AND receive responses without needing to manually setup MX records for each subdomain I'm interested in (bar.mydomain.com, baz.mydomain.com, etc.mydomain.com , ...)

[Mailgun docs show a setting on a domain](http://mailgun-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-domains.html#domains) called `wildcard` labeled "Mailgun allows you to receive email at multiple subdomains of a single domain without actually adding them. You still need to add the appropriate MX records for your subdomain(s) at your DNS provider" in the web ui.

A comment on [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/738331/100646) seems to hint that a new MX record would have to be made for each subdomain. I'd prefer not to have to do that and just keep it dynamic with something like this:

```
@                IN  MX  10  mxa.mailgun.org.
@                IN  MX  10  mxb.mailgun.org.
*.mydomain.com.  IN  MX  10  mxa.mailgun.org.
*.mydomain.com.  IN  MX  10  mxb.mailgun.org.
```

Does Mailgun support sending AND receiving from wildcard subdomains? and if so, what DNS records should be added (MX & SPF/DKIM)?

([This somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44303110/585552) doesn't list out the specifics.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just got a response from MG support

> We do not support sending from wildcard domain. We require each domain
>   you wish to send with be added and verified to our system with the
>   explicitly SMTP credentials or API endpoint used for sending.